# Torque half step/full step in stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, microstepping

At an exam, I was asked the following question:
A stepper motor has the greatest torque on its shaft in the 'halfstep/full step'.
Everywhere on the internet it says that full step gives the most torque. This was also the answer I indicated. I have already emailed this to my professor but he claims that: at half step 2 coils are energised, which gives a field that is the vectorial sum of the two separate fields. Therefore, this field is stronger than the field of 1 coil.
Is this correct? Does anyone know how I can prove him wrong?
Thanks in advance

https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/stepper-motors-and-drives-what-is-full-step-half-step-and-microstepping?fbclid=IwAR2MUsN_a6kuycMIjG03aCDG-VUX2Qo8_Cu-m22Z55MJ5eOaRMV_lrpyoKk

https://www.designnews.com/automation-motion-control/how-use-microstepping-get-more-torque?fbclid=IwAR2yoRQWDvsBXDLKji-x-ujFMGTtVjQgTkUnDN4tCGuV9Z01cQqWABnOjp0

Comment: Where on the internet does it say what you say it says? Links please.

Comment: It depends how half stepping is implemented so it may or may not be true. In any case field strength is not the only factor determining torque.

Comment: duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/316462/1743 ?

Comment: If you are specifically interested in holding torque when the motor is still, then sure, you could energize A=100% B=100%, which would in principle be more than the holding torque at a full step position when only one coil was A=100% B=0%. But modern drivers combine them as vectors, in which case the answer would be no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Stepper motor only** ..., [this note](https://www.faulhaber.com/fileadmin/user_upload_global/support/MC_Support/Motors/AppNotes/Faulhaber_AN001_EN.pdf)  figure 9

[image]

**With stepper driver** ...
From [this note](https://www.njr.com/electronic_device/PDF/application_notes/Stepper_motor_and_driver_selection_APP_E.pdf) , see "selecting driver mode", end of paper.

[image]

Seems to be a little error (or comparison) in legend ... for figure 12.

[image]

for half-stepping ... (comparing figure 10 and 12) ...

<<< Compared to full stepping (refer to figure 10 for the same driving conditions), a slightly-**higher torque** at low speed and a **small decrease** at higher step rates.>>>

**Not really very significant with this driver.**